# Proof for the conversion of nanometers to inverse centimeters

Tags: dimensional-analysis

This is probably an elementary question, but I can't seem to figure it out.
How does one convert nm to inverse cm?

For example, if I start with 10 nm, my first step would be to flip the fraction so it becomes 1/(10 nm)then just proceed normally. But I end up getting the wrong answer...

Answer (score 2):

You don't, any more than you convert metres to kilograms.  They are different dimensions.

Comment: It's actually common in physics when dealing with electromagnetic waves, for reasons that escape me; wavenumber (what gets expressed in cm${}^{-1}$) is the inverse of wavelength (what gets expressed in nm): look here http://www.impublications.com/wavenumber-wavelength-converter

Comment: But that's not a **conversion**.  The wave has two different quantities associated with it: wave number and wavelength.  One is a function of the other, but they are different things.  A conversion is when you express the same quantity in different units.